# Are there universal "neural signatures" definitive of "first languages"?

Tags: neurolinguistics

If we consider sign language and also communication methods of the deaf-blind, predominantly haptic language I believe, along with oral-audial language, is there data to justify the concept of a "native language"? In other words, is there a universal "signature" in terms of something like the speed of neural actions or reflexes, regarding an ability to use a language system? Or, a signature indicating how the *modality* of the first language has imprinted itself generally on neural and cognitive development (i.e., it is clear someone is a native speaker in sign language, perhaps because the language faculty has implanted itself and fused with certain bodily parts of the brains sensori-motor systems, as opposed to voice, mouth, esophagal neuronal controls, etc.)?

Comment: Not yet. Get a big grant and investigate.